# If power of an ideal is locally free then it is locally free

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, blow-ups

Let $X$ be a noetherian scheme and $\mathcal{I} \subset \mathcal{O}_X$ a coherent sheaf of ideals. Suppose that $\mathcal{I}^d$ is locally-free for some power $d$. Then the blowing up $\mathrm{Bl}_{\mathcal{I}^d} \to X$ is an isomorphism. However, $\mathrm{Bl}_{\mathcal{I}} \cong \mathrm{Bl}_{\mathcal{I}^d}$ as $X$-schemes so the map $\pi : \mathrm{Bl}_{\mathcal{I}} \to X$ is also an isomorphism. By definition of blowing up this implies that the inverse image of $\mathcal{I}$ which is equal to $\mathcal{I}$ is is locally-free.

My question is about a direct algebraic proof of this fact translated into commutative algebra:

Let $A$ be a noetherian local ring and $I \subset A$ be an ideal such that $I^d = (f)$ for some non zero-divisor $f$. Then $I = (g)$ for some non zero-divisor $g$.

I can see how to prove this when $A$ is a UFD but I don't see how a direct proof would go of the general case. Is there an easy argument or is it necessary to argue with the Rees Algebra?

Comment: That is not true.  For many rings, the ideal class group contains torsion elements that are not trivial.

Comment: @JasonStarr I had the same reservation, although I see how a local ring can have torsion in Cl(A) I don't know an example in which Pic(Spec(A)) has torsion which is what I am after. Does my sketched argument have a flaw?

Comment: @JasonStarr Isn't that about locally free ideals that are not free rather than ideals that are not locally free?

Comment: Being torsion in the class group means (assuming normal for simplicity) that $(I^n)^{**}$ is principal, which is weaker than $I^n$ principal.

Comment: I missed that the ring $A$ is assumed to be a local ring.

Comment: See https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09ME

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a proof if $A$ is an integral domain.

Let $x_1,\dots, x_n$ generate $I$. Then $\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{e_i}$ generate $I^d =f$  for vectors $e_i$ of nonnegative integers satisfying $\sum_i e_i=d$. These generators are all multiples of $f$ and can't all lie in the maximal ideal times $f$ so, since $A$ is local, one of them must be a unit times $f$. Fix such a generator $\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{e_i}$.

Without loss of generality, $e_1>0$.

Then for all $j$ from $1$ to $n$, $(x_j/x_1)\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{e_i}$ is also in $I^d$, thus is a multiple of $f$, hence is a multiple of $\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{e_i}$. Dividing by $x_1^{e_1-1} \prod_{i=2}^n x_i^{e_i}$, we see that $x_j$ is a multiple of $x_1$. Becuase this works for all $j$, $I=(x_1)$.